# How to return documents in mongoose and express js which are associated with only logged in user?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Here i have two mongoose models orders and users which have one to many relationship.

> user.model.js

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    firstname: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Name is required"],
    },
    lastname: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "LastName is required"],
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Email is required"],
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Password is required"],
    },

    isAdmin: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
export default User;
```

> order.model.js

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const orderSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    userId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
    customerId: { type: String },
    paymentIntentId: { type: String },
    products: [
      {
        id: { type: String },
        name: { type: String },
        category: { type: String },
        price: { type: String },
        size: { type: String },
        color: { type: String },
        thumbnail: { type: String },
        qty: { type: Number },
      },
    ],
    // subTotal: { type: Number, required: true },
    total: { type: Number, required: true },
    shipping: { type: Object, required: true },
    deliveryStatus: { type: String, default: "pending" },
    paymentStatus: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const Order = mongoose.model("Order", orderSchema);

export default Order;
```

I have some orders created by different users in my database. Now i am trying to get those specific orders associated with currently logged in user.

> order.controller.js

```
  export const getAllOrders = async (req, res) => {
  const { _id } = req.user;

  // console.log(typeof id);

  try {
    const orders = await Order.find({userId: _id});

    console.log(orders);
    res.status(200).json({ orders });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ msg: error.message });
  }
};
```

I have tried this one but it always return an empty array.

Comment: what is output of console.log(typeof _id) ? try by converting _id to mongoose object id with mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_id) and run your query

Comment: Its already a mongoose object id

Comment: Can you provide a sample data that's failing?